# How to replace text based on condition?

Tags: python

I am trying to replace the text "Last Week" from a column based on the below condition:
A prelude of the data:

1. Every Monday is the starting day of the week. For e.g. 8/2/21
2. Every Friday is the ending day of the week. For e.g. 8/6/21
   Hence, the week 8/2/21 - 8/6/21 is regarded as Week1.
3. Similarly for rest of the week in that month, i.e. Week2, Week3, Week4.
4. But the last week of the month is named as "Last Week".
   (In case if some final days of the month falls on weekdays, its taken as Week4/Week5)
   This is what needs to replaced.
   This method is similar for all Site IDs, as this last week text will be same.
   I need to replace this based on the dates provided.

   The logic will be:
   For a given Site ID, and if the second recent week has a status of Week3/Week4, then the last week should be replaced by Week4 or Week5.

How can it code it in python?

The table is given below:

```
Month   Start Date         Week           Week(Date)            Site ID
Aug'21  2-Aug-2022         Week1      08/02/2021 - 08/06/2021   AABC
Aug'21  9-Aug-2022         Week2      08/09/2021 - 08/13/2021   AABC
Aug'21  16-Aug-2022        Week3      08/16/2021 - 08/20/2021   AABC
Aug'21  23-Aug-2022        Last Week  08/23/2021 - 08/27/2021   AABC
```

TIA.

Comment: Read the text in from file, one line at a time, check for text being "Last Week" at that exact position (looks fixed width text), and replace with what you need. Write each line to new file as you process it.

Comment: Please give some more detail: Is the provided table saved in a string? Is there always only one month in the table? Can you give some code what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.